# How to efficiently perform addition over large loops in python

Tags: python

I am trying to perform addition in an efficient way in python over large loops . I am trying to loop over a range of 100000000.

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
sum = 0
for i in range(100000000):
    sum+=i
end_time = datetime.now()
print('--- %s seconds ---{}'.format(end_time - start_time))
print(sum)
```

The output from the above code is
--- %s seconds ---0:00:16.662666
4999999950000000

When i try to do it in C, its taking 0.43 seconds

From what i read, python creates new memory everytime when you perform addition to variable. I read some articles and came to know how to perform string concatenation in these situations by avoiding '+' sign . But i dont find anything how to do with integers.

Comment: Why loop? (n**2 +n)/2 will provide the same answer much faster than any loop.

Comment: There's a good chance C *does not* perform a loop, but just has the result stored in the binary. What use-case do you have that you must do this operation, but cannot simplify it to the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a comparison of three methods: your original way, using `sum(range(100000000))` as suggested by [Alex Metsai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66548349/120261), and using the NumPy numerical library's `sum` and `range` functions:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

def orig():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    sum = 0
    for i in range(100000000):
        sum+=i
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('--- %s seconds ---{}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print(sum)

def pyway():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    mysum = sum(range(100000000))
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('--- %s seconds ---{}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print(mysum)

def npway():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    sum = np.sum(np.arange(100000000))
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('--- %s seconds ---{}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print(sum)
```

On my computer, I get:

```
>>> orig()
--- %s seconds ---0:00:09.504018
4999999950000000
>>> pyway()
--- %s seconds ---0:00:02.382020
4999999950000000
>>> npway()
--- %s seconds ---0:00:00.683411
4999999950000000
```

NumPy is the fastest, if you can use it in your application.

But, as suggested by [Ethan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548162/how-to-efficiently-perform-addition-over-large-loops-in-python/66548508?noredirect=1#comment117643471_66548162) in a comment, it's worth pointing out that calculating the answer directly is *by far* the fastest:

```
def mathway():
    start_time = datetime.now()
    mysum = 99999999*(99999999+1)/2
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('--- %s seconds ---{}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print(mysum)


>>> mathway()
--- %s seconds ---0:00:00.000013
4999999950000000.0
```

I assume your actual problem is not so easily solved by pencil and paper :)

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the `sum()` function if you can process the list as a whole, which loops entirely in C code and is much faster, and also avoids the creation of new Python objects.

```
sum(range(100000000))
```

In my computer, your code takes `07.189210` seconds, while the above statement takes `02.751251` seconds, increasing the processing speed more than 3 times.

Edit: as suggested by [mtrw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120261/mtrw), numpy.sum() can speed up processing even more.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Metsei

Comment: What do you mean with "avoids the creation of new Python objects"?

Comment: In that you don't create a new list where you append to at each iteration.

Comment: The OP's code also doesn't do that (there's no list and therefore also no appends).

Comment: My mistake, I meant that he has a variable which he increases at each step, but that isn't of much importance now that I think about it, and after all I use a var too. Want to suggest an edit?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's half-true, in that the [partial *sums* aren't Python objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0ab152c6b5d95caa2dc1a30fa96e10258b5f188e/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2367) due to an optimization. The numbers produced by the `range` are still Python objects, though. Nah, don't really want to suggest an edit.

Comment: I see, OK then. Thanks for the insight BTW ^^